# Differences between SharePoint WCF Service Host Factories

Tags: sharepoint-server, wcf

There is three type of WCF service host factories in SharePoint 2010/2013:

1. `MultipleBaseAddressBasicHttpBindingServiceHostFactory` Basic HTTP binding must be used, which creates endpoints for a service based on the basic HTTP binding.
2. `MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory` The service factory creates endpoints with web bindings.
3. `MultipleBaseAddressDataServiceHostFactory` A data service host factory can be used.

What is main real difference between last two `MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory` and `MultipleBaseAddressDataServiceHostFactory`?

What are the main pros and cons between choosing one or another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory` for a REST service.

`Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory` dynamically creates the configuration hence no need to update `web.config` file of SharePoint web application. One thing to notice here is that you can’t access the service in browser with MEX endpoint. For example if you service is `http://server/service.svc`, then the URL `http://server/service.svc/mex` will not work for service created with `MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory`.

`MultipleBaseAddressDataServiceHostFactory` for an ADO.NET Data Service. The data services are best suited for providing data feed.